# Why does max (Operator) not return the longest list?

Tags: f#, max

I want to find the longest of two lists. Consider the following code sample:

```
let xs = ['B']
let ys = ['A'; 'B']
let longest = max xs ys
printfn "%A" longest
```

Contrary to my expectation the output of this program is `['B']` rather than `['A'; 'B']`.

Why does [`List<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370372.aspx) implement [`max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee353702(v=vs.100).aspx) this way? How/where exactly is this implementation defined?

I can see that `max` requires `comparison`, which I believe implies the implementation of `IComparable`. `List<'T>` does that automatically by making use of the [`StructuralComparison`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee353661(v=vs.100).aspx) attribute. But how does this automatic implementation look like?

What is the most concise alternative I can use to get the longest of two lists?

Comment: As Ewan Mellor mentions in his comment to Petr's answer, this is lexicographic order.  In other words, F# applies the same principle to lists that we apply to strings when we sort "apple" before "bee" even though "apple" is longer than "bee."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# compares lists element by element. As `'B' > 'A'` so it considers first list > second (lexicographic order) and breaks further comparison. You can use `.Length` property on list to compare lengths.
Like this for example;

```
let longest = if xs.Length > ys.Length then xs else ys
```

Result:

> ```
> val longest : char list = ['A'; 'B']
> ```

Comment: aka "lexicographic order"

Comment: Since List.length is O(N), where N is the size of the list, the complexity of this solution is O(N1+N2); performance suffers when the lists are long.  My answer includes an example that decomposes the lists in parallel and shortcuts the evaluation when it gets to the end of the shorter list, so its complexity is O(min(N1, N2)).

Comment: Sure, the author of the question asked for "the most concise alternative".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reusable function for checking the greater length of any 2 sequences:

```
let longest x y = match (Seq.length x > Seq.length y) with
                  |true -> x
                  |false -> y
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general way to compare two objects by some property you could create a `maxBy` function:

```
let maxBy f x y = Array.maxBy f [|x; y|]
```

then you can do:

```
let longest = maxBy List.length xs ys
```

or directly:

```
let longest = Array.maxBy List.length [|xs; ys|]
```

Comment: Rather than piggybacking on Array.maxBy, I'd just write my own maxBy function from scratch.  Among other benefits, it saves you from allocating an array.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `maxBy` function:

```
let maxBy f a b = if f b > f a then b else a
```

Then call it thus:

```
let longestList = maxBy List.length xs ys
```

Since List.length is O(N), performance will suffer if the lists are very long.  The operation will be O(N1 + N2), where N1 and N2 are the lengths of the lists.

Performance will suffer needlessly if one is long and the other is short.  To avoid that, you could write a more specific function.  This function is O(min(N1, N2)):

```
let getLongest list1 list2 =
    let rec helper = function
    | [], _ -> list2
    | _, [] -> list1
    | _ :: t1, _ :: t2 -> helper (t1, t2)
    helper (list1, list2)

let longestList = getLongest xs ys
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable function that will return the longest list from a **list of lists**:

```
let longest ll = ll |> List.sortBy List.length |> List.rev |> List.head
```

Examples:

```
> longest [xs; ys];;
val it : char list = ['A'; 'B']
> let zs = ['A' .. 'D'];;
val zs : char list = ['A'; 'B'; 'C'; 'D']
> longest [xs; zs; ys];;
val it : char list = ['A'; 'B'; 'C'; 'D']
```

However, it doesn't work if you input the empty list, as it'd be up to you do define exactly what you'd want the behaviour to be in that case.

Comment: you could avoid the call to `List.rev` sorting by negating `List.length` ; that way you just need to take the head if any (maybe wrapping the whole with option for the empty case) : `let longest xss = xss |> List.sortBy (List.length >> (*) -1) |> List.head`